# How to block certain apps (say games) except on weekends (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, windows-10, scheduled-tasks, blocking, security-policy

I am aware that applications can be blocked using 'Local Security Policy'. But how to combine it with Task Scheduling. I cannot find my way around the Task Scheduler.

Any other workaround is appreciated too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use
[Windows Parental Controls](https://news.microsoft.com/en-in/features/windows-10-parental-controls-feature/).

This will allow to
[create a free child account](https://www.howtogeek.com/666985/how-to-use-parental-controls-in-windows-10/)
and limit almost every aspect of his using the computer.

For more information see
[How to Set App & Game Limits on Windows 10](https://www.howtogeek.com/674189/how-to-set-app-game-limits-on-windows-10/).

Comment: Thanks. But I do not want to create a separate child account. This is for my main account.

Comment: We have had several such posts on our site and the result is always the same - there is nothing you can do that you cannot undo and often with just one click. The question is only how hard you can make it to undo. Having the games installed for another account (not necessarily a child account) will force you to logout off your main account, so it might be too bothersome to do. There are many solutions, but they really depend on you. Having someone else changing the password on the game account every week and divulging it only in the weekend is another idea that came up.

Comment: Now I realize. Thank you very much. I guess it is self-control then.